# Codename one: Not able to change Spanlabel style

Tags: codenameone

I am not able to change style of span label such as color,font.whenever I change style with codename one designer it doesn't reflect on app.
Is there any other way to change style of span label in codename one using codename one designer?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.getTextAllStyles()
```

instead of

```
.getAllStyles()
```

to modify the style of the text.

**Edit**

Sorry, I might have misunderstood you. 
In designer I guess you should modify the "Label" UIID.

Comment: He can also use `setTextUIID` then customize that in the designer